# What are the security threats when Googling and surfing when my Gmail account is open?

Tags: malware, gmail, threats, drive-by-download

Suppose I log to my Gmail account. After that, I use Google to search for random websites and visit some.

Are there any security threats on my Gmail account when Googling and surfing the net while it is open ?

This picture, hopefully, explains what I mean:

[image]

Comment: When your gmail account is open on **google.com**, try to  use **google.co.uk** or **google.ca** for all others services that doesn't require login.

Comment: @elsadek Thank you. But I have been wondering what  are the risks I could face in the scenario I described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main attack vectors are:

- [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29) - if there is a vulnerability on Google or Gmail then this could put you at risk.
- Browser bug - if there is a vulnerability in the particular browser you are using then it may be possible for a visited site to bypass the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) and that site could then access your data using client-side code (e.g. Javascript or Flash). This type of vulnerability has [existed in old](http://www.iss.net/security_center/reference/vulntemp/ie-same-origin-violation.htm) versions [of Internet Explorer](http://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2013-3908/).

In reality, the two above are unlikely. Google appear to be relatively tight on security, and now most browsers are auto-updating and tend to be quickly patched.

Answer (score 3):

Your gmail account will be safe unless someone finds a [Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF)](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29) vuln in gmail.

While nothing is 100% secure in the world, Google has proved to be very good at defending against security vulnerabilities. Even if a vulnerability is discovered, there is a good chance that it will be patched quickly. I rate it as highly unlikely that your account will be compromised in this manner.